# Import zip files into SAS

Tags: import, zip, sas

I am unable to import zip file into sas and I would really appreciate if you could help with this problem. Below is my code:

```
filename file1 saszipam '[my path]\EDataset-2000_06_20_193034-2000_06_26_211020.zip';
data dset;
infile file1(EDataset-2000_06_20_193034-2000_06_26_211020.txt) 
delimiter='09'x MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=1 ; 
   informat EI $3.;
   informat ID $5.;
   informat Region $1.;
   informat C_Number $23.;
   informat P_ID $13.;
   format EI $3.;
   format ID $5.;
   format Region $1.;
   format C_Number $23.;
   format P_ID $13.;
   input
          EI $ 1-3
          ID $ 4-8
          Region $ 9
          C_Number $ 10-32
          P_ID $ 33-45
              ;
if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;
```

The error I am getting is:"
ERROR: Invalid data length.
FATAL: Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.
       Aborted during the EXECUTION phase."

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: With no error given, we are not going to be able to help.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?

Comment: I am using SAS 9.3. I will shortly post the error I am receiving. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If SAS 9.4:

```
filename file1 zip '[my path]\EDataset-2000_06_20_193034-2000_06_26_211020.zip' 
        member='EDataset-2000_06_20_193034-2000_06_26_211020.txt";
data dset;
infile file1
    delimiter='09'x MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=1 ; 
   informat EI $3.;
   informat ID $5.;
   informat Region $1.;
   informat C_Number $23.;
   informat P_ID $13.;
   format EI $3.;
   format ID $5.;
   format Region $1.;
   format C_Number $23.;
   format P_ID $13.;
   input
          EI $ 1-3
          ID $ 4-8
          Region $ 9
          C_Number $ 10-32
          P_ID $ 33-45
              ;
if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;
```